# How does the Linux kernel retrieve ACPI tables from the system firmware?

Tags: linux-kernel, acpi, bios

When the Linux kernel boots, it retrieves the ACPI tables from the system firmware. After the system has booted, I can retrieve the tables from the running kernel memory with utilities such as `acpidump`

Maybe this question is not really Linux specific, because other OSes have to follow some comparable procedure, but I am still interested in how the Linux kernel retrieves them from the system firmware initially. I have looked at some kernel source code but can't get a straightforward answer how this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see: http://wiki.osdev.org/RSDP

The first step in retrieving the ACPI tables is finding the Root System Description Pointer, or RSDP.

On UEFI systems, it is conveniently given within the EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE.

On traditional BIOS systems, two memory areas need to be searched. First, in 16-bit real mode address 0x40E there will be a 2-byte segment pointer indicating where the Extended BIOS Data Area (EBDA) is located. The RSDP could be within the first 1 KiB of EBDA, identified by the string "RSD PTR ",  which is guaranteed to be located on a 16 byte boundary.

The other possible area is the main BIOS area below 1 MiB, or real-mode addresses 0x000E0000 to 0x000FFFFF.

Like all firmware (flash EEP)ROM contents, these are already copied to RAM ("shadowed") by the firmware itself for performance reasons: access to the non-volatile firmware store is usually fairly complicated and not very fast.

Comment: Thanks, your edit did clarify what puzzled me, I didn't knew about the shadowing part.

Comment: Back in 1992 or so, I had a '386 system that had an option to disable BIOS shadowing. By default, shadowing was enabled and I think the consensus already was that disabling it was a bad idea unless you had a specific reason to do that, and that it would impact your BIOS/DOS performance. Since then, the performance differential between the firmware (EEP)ROM and main system RAM has only increased.

Comment: On modern systems, the firmware builders won't even bother giving us the option to disable shadowing.